# How i can redirect an url with query string to the url without query string in NgInX?

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I need to redirect/rewrite an url that contains query string to the same url, but without query string. For example http://domain.com/a-post-title/?fbid=xyz to http://domain.com/a-post-title/
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy, just put a `?` at the end of your rewrite, 
from http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite:

```
If a replacement string includes the new request arguments, the previous request 
arguments are appended after them. If this is undesired, putting a question mark at the 
end of a replacement string avoids having them appended
```